# Can't edit or delete fields from custom content type (Drupal 9)

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I'm working on a clean install of Drupal 9. The first thing I did was create a couple of custom content types, and added some fields. But when I try to edit or delete the fields, I get a 404 error:

`The requested resource /admin/structure/types/manage/home_page/fields/node.home_page.body was not found on this server.`

I'm running on localhost using a standard PHP local server, and the default .htaccess file. Everything else seems to work okay, I've been able to navigate all around the admin area with no problems. It's just all the fields in content types.

I'm a new D9 developer, so please talk to me like I'm 8yrs old. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are running your web on built-in PHP web server with: `php -S localhost:<port>`

Try this command instead: `php -S localhost:<port> .ht.router.php`

Note: `.ht.router.php` file is in the root folder of your site. An in depth explanation can be found on the comments of it.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you so much, I hadn't seen that in any tutorials or anything before.